# ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: php

Esto me funciona correctamente para que mi explorador funcione:

```
$Materia = 'Matemáticas';
$root_dir = 

"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\archivos\\".$_SESSION['grado']."\\".$_SESSION['grupo']. "\\" 
. $Materia . "\\" .$_SESSION['apellido_paterno']." 
".$_SESSION['apellido_materno']." ".$_SESSION['nombre']. "\\";
```

Y esto no me funciona para nada, tomando en cuenta que cuando imprimo la variable con un echo me imprime correctamente el nombre de la misma, dicha variable la traigo por link de otro php.

```
$Materia = $_GET['Materia'];
$root_dir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\archivos\\".$_SESSION['grado']."\\".$_SESSION['grupo']. 
"\\" . $Materia . "\\" .$_SESSION['apellido_paterno']." 
".$_SESSION['apellido_materno']." ".$_SESSION['nombre']. "\\";
```

--EDIT--
Note que mi variable que obtengo por link conflictua con esta funcion

```
function list() {
            var hashval = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            $.get('?do=list&file=' + hashval, function(data) {
                $tbody.empty();
                $('#breadcrumb').empty().html(renderBreadcrumbs(hashval));
                if (data.success) {
                    $.each(data.results, function(k, v) {
                        $tbody.append(renderFileRow(v));
                    });
                    !data.results.length && $tbody.append('<tr><td class="empty" colspan=5>Esta carpeta está vacia</td></tr>')
                    data.is_writable ? $('body').removeClass('no_write') : $('body').addClass('no_write');
                } else {
                    console.warn(data.error.msg);
                }
                $('#table').retablesort();
            }, 'json');
        }
```

Alguna idea amigos?

Comment: Mira como hacer un [mcve].

Comment: Otra cosa que estás haciendo mal es duplicar preguntas, porque ya tienes [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425365/ay%c3%badenme-con-php-de-favor) sobre el mismo problema.

Comment: @RamiroBarone ya escribí el código, también deje el video para explicar.

Comment: Puedo decir todo ¿? por que en realidad hay bastantes cosas que corregir.

Comment: ¿Qué significa *cuando imprimo la variable con un echo me imprime correctamente el nombre de la misma*? ¿Qué error da tu código, qué hace, qué no hace? La pregunta está incompleta, no mencionas el comportamiento del código ni muestras el uso que haces de tu variable.

Comment: @Excorpion si, puedes decirme todo lo que veas mal porfavor.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la pagina no entra a la ruta cuando la variable la tomo del get, aun cuando contiene exactamente la materia que le estoy solicitando, pienso que podría ser un error de lenguaje de codificación por ejemplo utf8

Comment: Si la materia está bien, entonces, imprime en pantalla la ruta para saber si es ahí donde algo falla, tal vez espacios que no corresponden. ¿Qué aparece en pantalla si agregas `var_dump($root_dir, is_dir($root_dir));`?

Comment: @Triby `C:\xampp\htdocs\c.php:62:string 'C:/xampp/htdocs/archivos/archivos/1/A/Matemáticas/Hernández Arguelles Rigoberto Ernesto' (length=89)
C:\xampp\htdocs\c.php:62:boolean false`

Comment: @Triby creo que la variable se pasa por html y en mi código va primero php, algun consejo?

Comment: ¿Ese `false` proviene de [`is_dir($root_dir)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir)? Entonces no existe el directorio y ese es el problema. Revisa el código fuente en el navegador, tal vez se estén remplazando tildes y `Matemáticas` aparezca como `Matem&aacute;ticas`

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que veo es que estás usando SESSION sin iniciar session... 
cosa que no se puede. - [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)

```
session_start(); //Sin esto, no podrás usar SESSION
//Verificando si $_GET contiene datos, es cuando asignamos el valor a una variable
if(isset($_GET['Materia'])){
    $Materia = $_GET['Materia'];
}else{
    echo "No se ha cargado Materia";
    exit;
}
// Deberías revisar siempre si cada SESSION se ha cargado, usando isset() ...
$grado = $_SESSION['grado'];
$grupo = $_SESSION['grupo'];
$apMaterno = $_SESSION['apellido_materno'];
$apPaterno = $_SESSION['apellido_paterno'];
$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre']

$root_dir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\archivos\\".$grado."\\".$grupo."\\". $Materia ."\\" .$apPaterno."\\".$apMaterno."\\".$nombre."\\";
```

Comment: Comprobé con el isset y todo bien, pero luego revise en network que me conflictúa con una función, ya añadí la función al post, alguna idea brother?

Comment: La idea es que actualices el post si haces cambios.. ahora, si aparecen errores, debes proporcionarlos igualmente... como se que hiciste ?